# Why do I need to 'import 'framework'?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I'm working on a personal project and I've installed Firebase with Cocoapods and imported it in the bridging-header.

My question is why do I get an error if I try to use a Firebase method in my project if I haven't written `import Firebase` at the top? The same can be said for Google Analytics etc.

The reason I ask is because in this tutorial: [Ray Wenderlich Firebase Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/109706/firebase-tutorial-getting-started)

Firebase is configured the same way as mine - but none of the documents contain `import Firebase`, and the project recognizes any Firebase method universally without errors.

I know I can just use `import` but I don't understand what I am doing differently and would rather not have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think u have in pod file line:

use_frameworks!

delete it and reinstall pods it should help

Answer (score 2):

In the mentioned project, the import is done from the `Grocr-Bridging-Header.h`, it's actually an Objective-C import:

```
#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>
```

The reason why the import was done from Objective-C is beause the project is quite old and Cocoapods didn't have support for Swift then.

Comment: you're right I forgot to mention that I also imported in the bridging-header - I used the word 'included'  - will specify now.

Comment: @SamYoungNY The project is old. CocoaPods didn't have support for Swift then. Nowadays the correct solution is to use `use_frameworks!` as described in the other answer.

Comment: OK - so what I'm deducing is that for older projects you have to `import` in the bridging header and therefore can omit using `import` in your .swift files - including `use_frameworks!` in the Podfile works for newer projects?

Comment: thank you @Sulthan I understand thanks for the explanation. However - since I am using a few frameworks I would rather not have to do it the newer way (it eliminates a few lines at the top). Will the old way of installing the pods cause any problems down the line? The project does build the "old way". I don't want to trade-off shaving a few lines at the cost of reliability

Comment: @SamYoungNY In programming the best way is to import frameworks only where the frameworks are actually needed, that's why the newer way is superior. The old way will make the framework available to all your swift headers. `use_frameworks!` also fixes some problems, e.g. for `@IBDesignable`. See https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/